# Svelte onDestroy not called if parent removed by {#if}

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to understand why `onDestroy()` fires in some situations but not others. In the below pseudo-code it does not work as I would think it should:

```
[App.svelte]
<script>
  let panels=[]
</script>

{#if panels.length === 0}
  <!--- show another component to create the first panel --->
{:else}
  <ComponentA bind:panels />
{/if}


[ComponentA.svelte]
<script>
  export let panels
  import { onDestroy } from 'svelte'
  onDestroy(() => {console.log("DESTROYING COMPONENT A")})
</script>

{#each panels as panel (panel.id) }
  <ComponentB {panel} />
{/each}


[ComponentB.svelte]

<script>
  export let panel
  import { onDestroy } from 'svelte'
  onDestroy(() => {console.log("DESTROYING COMPONENT B")})
</script>
```

In the above simplified mock-up of my code, if the last panel is removed (`panels.length === 0`) the `{#if}` block removes `ComponentA` (and replaces it with something else not shown). When this happens, `ComponentA` is destroyed (I see "`DESTROYING COMPONENT A`" in the log), but `ComponentB` is *not* destroyed (there is never a "`DESTROYING COMPONENT B`" in the log).

If however I rewrite the top component (App.svelte) like this:

```
[App.svelte]
<script>
  let panels=[]
</script>

{#if panels.length === 0}
  <!--- show another component to create the first panel --->
{/if}

<ComponentA bind:panels />
```

So that `ComponentA` is never removed (maybe CSS `display: none` or something instead), then I *do* see "DESTROYING COMPONENT B" because of the `{#each}` block within `ComponentA` now operating on an empty array. It's as if the destruction of `componentA` is preventing `{#each}` from destroying the components under it.

Why is this? Does it have to do with the bind being removed?

Comment: That should not happen, the given example is not representative of your issue. See [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d74458b018a04ce99c6e046a04f9bccb?version=3.56.0) that behaves exactly as expected.